# Git Job conditional allow failure tag

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have written the git job.

Requirement - If test cases fail with 429 error, pipeline should allow failure. If test cases have any other error it should fail.

Current Implementation

```
integration_test3.8:
  stage: test
  variables:
    PY: 38
  timeout: 2h
  <<: *cache_readonly
  <<: *init_bot_creds
  <<: *only_master_merge_request_and_nightly_build
  needs:
    - prepare-3.8
    - select-bot-account
  script:
    - !reference [.setup_olp_cli, script]
    - source activate $CONDA_ENV
    - mkfifo fifo_pipe
    - make test 2>&1 | tee fifo_pipe &
    - test_output=$(cat fifo_pipe)
    - >
      if echo "$test_output" | grep -q "429" && echo "$test_output" | grep -q "FAIL"; then
        echo "Test encountered a 429 error and other failures."
        exit 1
      elif echo "$test_output" | grep -q "429"; then
        echo "Test encountered a 429 error, but allowed failure."
        exit 0
      elif echo "$test_output" | grep -q "FAIL"; then
        echo "Test failed."
        exit 1
      else
        echo "All tests passed."
        exit 0
      fi
    - mv integration-tests/test-results integration_results38/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - integration_results38
      - integration-tests/junit.xml
    reports:
      junit: integration-tests/junit.xml
```

Currently its not passing even if only 429 occours.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Test first if your make done in background is the issue:

```yaml
    script:
      - !reference [.setup_olp_cli, script]
      - source activate $CONDA_ENV
      - mkfifo fifo_pipe
      - make test 2>&1 | tee fifo_pipe
      - test_output=$(cat fifo_pipe)
      - >
        if echo "$test_output" | grep -q "429" && echo "$test_output" | grep -q "FAIL"; then
          echo "Test encountered a 429 error and other failures."
          exit 1
        elif echo "$test_output" | grep -q "429"; then
          echo "Test encountered a 429 error, but allowed failure."
          exit 0
        elif echo "$test_output" | grep -q "FAIL"; then
          echo "Test failed."
          exit 1
        else
          echo "All tests passed."
          exit 0
        fi
      - mv integration-tests/test-results integration_results38/
```

The `make test` command will block (i.e., prevent the script from proceeding) until it is done, which will automatically ensure that your `fifo_pipe` has been fully written to by the time you read from it.